# jQuery mobile controlgroup

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile

I have a custom template with jQuery-mobile included. The problem is that the most of buttons are in `data-role="controlgroup"` - it is fine, because it also resizes and centers elements, but now i have table in which i need to use some buttons and as a result jQuery mobile tries to show it in one group with rounded corner.

```
<div data-role="fieldcontain">
    <fieldset data-role="controlgroup">
        <table>
            <tr><td></td><td>Name</td><td></td></tr>
            <tr><td>1</td><td>ADS</td><td><a href="#" data-role="button" data-ajax="false">Run</a></td></tr>
            <tr><td>2</td><td>ASDF</td><td><a href="#" data-role="button" data-ajax="false">Run</a></td></tr>
            <tr><td>3</td><td>ASD</td><td><a href="#" data-role="button" data-ajax="false">Run</a></td></tr>
            <tr><td>4</td><td>ASDF</td><td><a href="#" data-role="button" data-ajax="false">Run</a></td></tr>
        </table>
    </fieldset>
</div>
```

[image: Corners]

So is it possible to use `data-role="controlgroup"` and dont show round corners in table or show for each?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You would need to write your own CSS rule for buttons in controlgroup that are within a table column. You will also need to put those rules **after** original jQuery Mobile CSS definition (i.e. at the end of `jquery-mobile.css` or into your own CSS file that's inluded after jQuery Mobile's). Something along these lines:

```
table td .ui-controlgroup-controls .ui-corner-top, table td .ui-controlgroup-controls .ui-corner-bottom {
        -moz-border-radius: .6em /*{global-radii-blocks}*/;
        -webkit-border-radius: .6em /*{global-radii-blocks}*/;
        border-radius: .6em /*{global-radii-blocks}*/;
        -moz-border-radius: .6em /*{global-radii-blocks}*/;
        -webkit-border-radius: .6em /*{global-radii-blocks}*/;
        border-radius: .6em /*{global-radii-blocks}*/;
}
```